# Select From database when multiple checkbox checked

Tags: c#, database, checkbox

How can i select multiple rows from database when multiple checkbox
have been checked. here's the code.if you look at the line where i used query string
there is double Request that i don't know what else i have to insert.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Checkbox");
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Brands";
    var select = db.Query(sql);
    dynamic execute = "";
    List<String> selected = new List<string>();
    int count = 0;
    List<dynamic> exec = new List<dynamic>();


    if(IsPost){
        if(Request["List"] == null){
            Response.Redirect("~/Checkbox");
        }
        selected = Request["List"].Split(',').ToList();

        count = Request["List"].Count();

        var sqls = "SELECT * FROM Brands WHERE Name = @0 OR Name = @1";
        exec = db.Query(sqls, Request["List"], Request["List"]);



}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Checkbox Multiple</title> 
</head>
<body>
    @foreach(var values in exec){
        <span>@values.BrandID</span>
    }

    <form method="post" action="">
    @foreach(var item in select){
    <label>@item.Name</label>     
    <input type="checkbox" multiple="multiple" name="List" value="@item.Name"><br>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Send">    
        </form>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using in query and construct a comma separated string and pop it in the query.

```
string inClause = "1, 2, 3";

var sqls = "SELECT * FROM Brands WHERE Name in (" + inClause +")";
```

Comment: Be careful for SQL Injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a SQL function that split a coma seperated list

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]      
(      
 @RowData varchar(8000),      
 @SplitOn nvarchar(5)      
)       
RETURNS @RtnValue table      
(      
 Id int identity(1,1),      
 Data nvarchar(100)      
)      
AS       
BEGIN      
 Declare @Cnt int      
 Set @Cnt = 1      

 While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)      
 Begin      
  Insert Into @RtnValue (data)      
  Select      
   Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))      

  Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))      
  Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1      
 End      

 Insert Into @RtnValue (data)      
 Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))      

 Return      
END
```

Now you can pass a comma separated list to this function.

Suppose 
@configIds ='1,2,3,4,6,17'
It will insert data for each ID separably

```
 INSERT INTO ABC      
(ID,patient_id,created_user,created_date)      
SELECT data, @patient_Id, @created_user, Getdate()FROM Split(@configIds,',')
```

or It could be used while Updating the new checkbox list selected record
First delete the record which are not in the comma separated list (@configIds)

```
DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID IN                     
( SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM ABC WHERE Patient_ID=@patient_Id                                       
AND ID NOT in (SELECT Ltrim(Rtrim(Data)) FROM Split(@configIds,','))                    
)
```

Update Code.....

After the delete block set Update flag to true or update the record based on the newly selected record of the checkboxlist